# Universal Algebra & Free Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Q: Let $f$ be the embedding (injective homomorphism) of $A$ into $Str(A): a \in A$ is sent to the corresponding string of length $1$.

Prove that $(f; \langle Str(A), \hat{}, ()\rangle )$ is the free monoid where $\hat{} $ is an associative binary operation with identity $()$ on $A$.

Notes:

i) Question is in the setting of Universal Algebra.

ii) $\hat{}$ is concatenation of string, i.e. attach two strings together.

iii) I have already shown $\langle Str(A), \hat{}, () \rangle$ is a monoid, only need to show $(f; \langle Str(A), \hat{}, ()\rangle )$ is a free algebra.

Comment: You have the correct choice of operation! What is your definition of "free algebra"? It will help to start by writing down what you need to show.

Answer (score 1):

You state you have shown it is a monoid,

So you have shown $\hat{}$ is associative and that the structure has identity which you denote as $()$, seemingly the empty string

This is related to [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)

Appears all that is left is to show that the elements of $A$ under $f$ are free generators for $(A \text{ under } f)^*$ (the Kleene star of $A$ under $f$ and since $f$ embeds $A$ into $Str(A)$, we have $f(a) = a$ which is the string of length 1 as you say,
we can take $A = \{a_1,...a_n\} =\{f(a_1), \ldots, f(a_n)\} $ as your free-generators.

Perhaps $A$ is not finite by assumption which is fine, I just use a finite set to be illustrative in my explanation.

Comment: "related to Kleene star" is an understatement -- the Kleene star construction *is* the word monoid / free monoid construction!

Comment: Yes you are correct; however, my choice of wording is so the OP is then motivated to investigate this.